# Replace, based on other value in DF

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, row

I have a dataframe and like to replace certain values if other values in the same row meet a specific condition, e.g.:

```
DF <- data.frame(a= c(2,4,67),
                 b= c("TSS",".","TSS"),
                 c= c(3,46,5),
                 d= c(45,"-",47))
```

resulting in:

```
   a   b  c  d
1  2 TSS  3 45
2  4   . 46  - 
3 67 TSS  5 47
```

Now I'd like to replace values in row 2 column c and d with "." and [2,c], respectively, if the value of [2,b] is ".". The result would look like this:

```
   a   b  c  d
1  2 TSS  3 45
2  4   .  . 46   
3 67 TSS  5 47
```

I tried using a for loop, but since I have a huge dataset this takes too much time. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  a = c(2, 4, 67),
  b = c("TSS", ".", "TSS"),
  c = c(3, 46, 5),
  d = c(45, "-", 47),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


DF$d[DF$b == "."] <- DF$c[DF$b == "."]
DF$c[DF$b == "."] <- "."
```

First we replace the d-Value in rows where b is a "." with the value from c. The second line then replaces the value in c with a ".".

```
> DF
   a   b c  d
1  2 TSS 3 45
2  4   . . 46
3 67 TSS 5 47
```

Comment: This does not generalize. What happens with more columns or If the `"."` is found in another column?

Comment: True, it does not generalize. I thought OP wanted an answer for this specific case. I guess a generalized solution would be to shift the rows where the "." occurs, starting at the column after the "." and filling it up with another ".".

Comment: I agree with your logic. Please go ahead and edit your answer to include the generalized case so more users can benefit from this.